# Question about $[K:F]=[K:E][E:F]$ for fields $E,F,K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

This is probably a dumb question.

We have a theorem that states

> If $E$ is a finite extension field of a field $F$, and $K$ is a finite extension field of $E$, then $K$ is a finite extension of $F$, and
>   $$
> [K:F]=[K:E][E:F],
> $$
>   where $[E:F]$ is the degree $n$ of $E$ over $F$.

I don't quite think I understand this fully. Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$, $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, and $F=\mathbb{Q}$. Then (according to the theorem)

\begin{equation}
[\mathbb{Q}(i):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(i):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}].
\end{equation}
But $[\mathbb{Q}(i):\mathbb{Q}]=2$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=2$, so wouldn't that imply $[\mathbb{Q}(i):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]=1$ and so $\mathbb{Q}(i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$? But this cannot be (right)?

What is the error in my thinking that's leading to this apparent contradiction? As far as I know the fields $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Q}(i),$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ satisfy the hyptheses. I'm sure I'm looking over something simple, but I'm pulling my hair out over here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ doesn't contain $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, so it is not a field extension.

Comment: Wow. Thank you you all. I knew it was something simple. If someone puts an answer I'll gladly mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in this reasoning is that $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ does not contain $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.  Any element $x$ of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ has the form $x=a+bi$ for $a$, $b\in\mathbb{Q}$. Then for $x^2=(a^2-b^2)+2abi$ to be real, either $a$ or $b$ must be zero.  If $a$ is zero, $x^2$ is nonpositive and does not equal $2$, and if $b$ is zero, $x^2=a^2$ is the square of a rational and does not equal $2$.  Therefore $\sqrt{2}\notin\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: This answer was already given in the comments before.